# Why do the elementary theory of the finite fields uses Chebotarev's theorem for global fields rather than for number fields?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, model-theory

James Ax proved that the elementary theory of the finite fields is decidable. I found its proof on the book Fried, Jarden: "Field Arithmetic 3rd edition". Fried writes on the beginning of the chapter 6.3 that $K$ is a global field. There is a Theorem 6.3.1 b):

"Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of global fields and let $\mathcal C$ be a conjugacy class in $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$. Then the Dirichlet's density of $\{\mathfrak p\in P(K)|\left (\frac{L/K}{\mathfrak p}\right )=\mathcal C\}$ exists and is equal to $|\mathcal C|/[L:K]$."

Then on the page 446. Jarden denotes the following:

For given sentence $\theta$ of $\mathcal{L} (\operatorname{ring})$ denote $S(\theta)=S(K,1,\theta)=\{\sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(K)|\tilde K(\sigma)\models \theta\}$ and $A(\theta)=A(K,\theta)=\{\mathfrak p\in P(K)|\bar K_{\mathfrak p}\models \theta\}$.

Here $P(K)$ is defined on the page 115: The set of prime divisors of $K/\mathbb F_q$ is denoted by $P(K)$.

Now, the Theorem 6.3.1 is used in proving the Lemma 20.9.2 b: "Let $\lambda$ be the test sentence
$$p((∃X)[f_1 (X) = 0], . . . , (∃X)[f_m (X) = 0]),$$
where $f_1 , . . . , f_m ∈ K[X]$ are separable polynomials and $p$ is a Boolean polynomial. Let $B$ be the set of all $\mathfrak p ∈ P (K)$ such that all coefficients of $f_i$
are $\mathfrak p$-integral and the leading coefficient and the discriminant of the $f_i$ ’s are $p$-units, $i = 1, . . . , m$. Denote the splitting field of $f_1 · · · f_m$ over $K$ by $L$. Let $\bar S=\{\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)|L(\sigma)\models \lambda\}$. Then $\sigma(A(\lambda))=|\bar S(\lambda)|/[L:K]$."

It looks like $B$ is used only in Lemma 20.9.2 a, not in 20.9.2 b.

Now, the book says that Lemma 20.9.2 b follows from the Theorem 6.3.1 b.

Why do we need the assumption that in Theorem 6.3.1 b we use global fields instead of number fields as in https://mdimeglio.github.io/papers/Chebotarevs_density_theorem.pdf Theorem 2.1?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @reuns Oh. Well, I think the numbered formula (1) is not necessary. I removed it. Is the question now clearer or is there still something unclear?

Comment: You haven’t defined what $K$ was, after “Then on the page 446…” or in Lemma 20.9.2(b). Regardless, it’s perfectly possible that the author decided to state Cebotarev in full generality, even though they used it for only a special kind of field.

Comment: I think Aphelli has given the real answer. If F&J want to prove Chebotarev for all global fields in their book, they should not have to prove it separately for number fields when an application later in the book uses Chebotarev only for number fields. As an analogy, if an algebraic geometry book proves the Nullstellensatz for all algebraically closed fields and cites this later to prove a result about complex algebraic varieties, should the reader think that proof is using the Nullstellensatz for all algebraically closed fields or recognize that only the special case of $\mathbf C$ is used?

Comment: @Aphelli I though that $K$ is defined to be a global field.